# Laravel global softdelete

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How do I turn on softDelete for all of my models without having to specify the following in each and every?:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class ListItem extends Eloquent
{
    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $table = 'list_items';
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function product(){
        return $this->hasOne('Product');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a `BaseModel` class. This let's you share all kind of functionality and configuration across multiple of your models:

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {
    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

And then let your models extend that class

```
class ListItem extends BaseModel {
    public function product(){
        return $this->hasOne('Product');
    }
}
```

---

By the way, `list_items` is already the conventional table name (snake_case and plural) so you don't have to specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use a base class. Have all your models extend a class that, in turn, extends Eloquent. Then, you can put anything that affects all models in the base class.